# How to include table name in json object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, database

I want to return a JSON object with a table name included. How can I add a property in the response?

```
{
  "table": "tableName",
  "results": [
    
  ]
}
```

Currently I am returning the json response like this:

```
// result is an array of objects.
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Please show expected output. What do you mean by the "table name [being] generated"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your looping through the results of a database query, it won't include the table name unless you manually add it to the response...

`$json_response = array('table' => 'table name here', 'results' => array())`;

and..

```
array_push($json_response['results'],$row_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the table name is not returned by the database!

If you want to return it, wrap your `$json_response` object into another array. For example.

```
echo json_encode(array('table_name' => $json_response))
```

Thus said, you're using mysql_* functions which are **unsafe** and **deprecated**. Please switch to MySQLi or PDO and to prepared statements.

Comment: Could you tell me what i should change?

Comment: There's nothing you should change. SQL queries never return the name of the table. But you can just replace your "echo" line with the one I posted above, adjusting 'table_name'.

Comment: And if you mean "what I should change for the database"... Then stop following guides written for PHP4 and use the new database drivers: php.net/mysqli or php.net/pdo . Note that the extension you're using, MySQL (not "i"), is deprecated. @ImAtWar